# EV Driver Authorization using RFID in OCPP protocol

Tags: python, embedded, ocpp

I am new to OCPP protocol and I am building a Python OCPP server that can communicate with an EV charger using OCPP protocol. This server has the feature "Authenticate user via RFID".  I have created 2 Python files which are Charge_Stattion.py:

```
# Charge_Stattion.py


import asyncio
import logging
import websockets

from ocpp.v201 import call
from ocpp.v201 import ChargePoint as cp

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class ChargePoint(cp):

    
    async def authentication(self):
        request = call.AuthorizePayload(
            id_token={'id_token':'AA12345',
                    'type': 'ISO14443'})
        response = await self.call(request)
        print(response)



async def main():
   async with websockets.connect(
       'ws://localhost:9000/CP_1',
        subprotocols=['ocpp2.0.1']
   ) as ws:

       cp = ChargePoint('CP_1', ws)

       await asyncio.gather(cp.start(), cp.authentication())


if __name__ == '__main__':
   asyncio.run(main())
```

and Central_System.py:

```
#Central_System.py


import asyncio
import logging
import websockets
from datetime import datetime

from ocpp.routing import on
from ocpp.v201 import ChargePoint as cp
from ocpp.v201 import call_result
from ocpp.v201.enums import AuthorizationStatusType, Action

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class ChargePoint(cp):
   @on('BootNotification')
   async def on_boot_notification(self, charging_station, reason, **kwargs):
      return call_result.BootNotificationPayload(
         current_time=datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
         interval=10,
         status='Accepted'
      )
   
   @on(Action.Authorize)
   async def on_authorize(self, id_token):
       return call_result.AuthorizePayload(id_token_info={"status": AuthorizationStatusType.accepted})


async def on_connect(websocket, path):
    """ For every new charge point that connects, create a ChargePoint
    instance and start listening for messages.
    """
    try:
        requested_protocols = websocket.request_headers[
            'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol']
    except KeyError:
        logging.info("Client hasn't requested any Subprotocol. "
                 "Closing Connection")
    if websocket.subprotocol:
        logging.info("Protocols Matched: %s", websocket.subprotocol)
    else:
        # In the websockets lib if no subprotocols are supported by the
        # client and the server, it proceeds without a subprotocol,
        # so we have to manually close the connection.
        logging.warning('Protocols Mismatched | Expected Subprotocols: %s,'
                        ' but client supports  %s | Closing connection',
                        websocket.available_subprotocols,
                        requested_protocols)
        return await websocket.close()

    charge_point_id = path.strip('/')
    cp = ChargePoint(charge_point_id, websocket)
    logging.info("abcxyz: %s", charge_point_id)
    await cp.start()


async def main():
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect,
        '0.0.0.0',
        9000,
        subprotocols=['ocpp2.0.1']
    )
    logging.info("WebSocket Server Started")
    await server.wait_closed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Following the document [here](https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp/blob/master/docs/v201/OCPP-2.0.1_part2_specification.pdf), I understand that the user must present an RFID card first, then the Charge Station will send an AuthorizeRequest containing idToken from this RFID card to Central System, then Central System will send and AuthorizeResponse to Charge Station. In the 2 python files above, I have implemented the process Charge Station sends andAuthorizeRequest to Central System and Central System sends back AuthorizeResponse to Charge Station. This [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhidC.jpg) demonstrates these processes

My questions are:

- How can I implement the process EV driver present an RFID card to Charge Station. Should I create 2 other python files which represent EV driver and RFID card?
- How can I know whether Center System accept this authentication and how to implement this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple flow

1. EV owner registers himself as a EV client on some server where the server provides an unique id, like "unique-client-id" and stores this value as `idTag` on a database.
2. When this client go to charge to some charging station, he inputs that unique id to charging device which sends the id in the following form via websocket connection:

```
[3, "unique-id-representing-the-current-msg", "Authorize", {"idTag": "unique-client-id"}]
```

3. OCPP server receives that message, and looks for received `idTag` on the database, if it exists it will send back response like below:

```
[4, "unique-id-representing-the-current-msg", {"idTagInfo": {"status": "Accepted"}}]
```

I recommend using sanic framework since it has both websocket and http support by default.